# Why do we define a statefunction like this: $\oint$ dφ = 0

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

Our teacher described an arbitary statefunction φ such that it  follows $\oint dφ=0$
I know statefunctions do not depend on the path taken, but what does the integral being 0 mean?
Also, i'm in high school and we have just started thermodynamics, so kindly correct if i've made any mistakes.

Comment: Didn’t your teacher explain what it means?

Comment: You're doing loop integerals in high school? You're doing state functions in high school? You're doing thermodynamics in high school? Anyway, it seems like you are referring to the change in a thermodynamic state function being independent of the path means it is only a function of the conditions of the system, but the context is kind of sparse.

Comment: @Swastik just out of curiosity, where are you from?

Comment: @Dan yes, at a basic level though.

Comment: @BobD India, not Germany, what people usually say to me haha.

Comment: Usually want to wait a day or two before giving a green check mark. That way other people are encouraged to try to put in more complete answers.

Comment: Oh right, i'm new here so i don't know much about how the community works, thanks!

Comment: @Swastik actually I figured it was India. I am amazed at how many India high schoolers ask questions on this site and also curious as to why.

Comment: @BobD thermodynamics is an important topic in Indian high school physics and chemistry syllabus. Also majority of Indian high schoolers prepare for competitive examinations like JEE and NEET (which are overhyped here in India) . So many of them end up in online platforms like physics stack exchange, quora etc to clarify their doubts, asking homework type questions they get from coaching institutes etc

Comment: @KP99 Thanks for the input. I recently answered a question (on friction) for an Indian student who was not able to get an answer from teachers. See the paragraph where he discusses a question on the JEE exam here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/681511/a-block-connected-to-a-string-is-kept-on-a-rough-surface-if-an-external-force-i/681887#681887

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sign
$$\oint $$
means that you are doing integral (adding) of function in some loop. Consider the following figure:
[image]

It's clear that we can write this integral as some of the two integral:
$$\oint =\int_{\Gamma_1}+\int_{-\Gamma_2}=0\rightarrow \int_{\Gamma_1}=\int_{\Gamma_2}$$
Note the direction of the integral $\Gamma_i$. The above says that the addition between the two points is independent of the path taken. In other words, the function is a state function.

Comment: Maybe you want to expand on that a bit. Why is path independece relevant to being a state function? That is, it refers to a *thermodynamic* state function, which can only be a function of the conditions of the system and not the path it took to get there. It is fairly clear how energy gets that characteristic, or temperture. But for entropy this is a crucial consideration. Which I didn't get until half way through 3rd year university, so I'm surprised it's getting talked about in high school.

Comment: @Dan OP has mentioned that he knows that state function is independent of path. But he didn't understand, What it has to do with integral, So I explain that.

Answer (score 0):

The “loop”, as you call it, is any thermodynamic cycle. If you sum up all the changes of any state function (pressure, temperature, internal energy, entropy, etc.) of a system over a complete cycle it will equal zero. It simply means each equilibrium state of a system  has a unique set of property values.  It does not apply to heat and work as they are not state functions.

Hope this helps